# What is the best way to insert Null Data Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking on my project to create an entry on my database wuth PHP and MySQL.
I've created an class "Order" and iside this class I have a function to create a new entry in my Database.

On my code I want to reuse this function, but hte fact is, when i create the entry I haven't all the Datas (Some Datas are inserted later in the process).
So my question is the next one. What is the best to manage it ?

Should I generate some data as NULL ? (that's my fort idea) Like that ?

```
 $unknow = NULL;
 $end_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 month"));
 $user = checkConnected($bdd);
 Order::create($bdd, $new_full_modele_devis_path, $unknow, $end_date, 0, $user->getId(), $unknow, $entreprise->getId());
```

or should I rework my finction to ignore empty  datas ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I would recommend skipping those columns on the insert and letting the database fill in the NULL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make your database structure you can set default values of your fields. In your case if a field may not be filled in you can set the default value as `NULL` meaning you don't need to touch that field in your code until you want to save a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let database fill the NULL values. Make those fields nullable in database which you want to insert later.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to save the null values. Instead you set the default values so that when there is null value then it would save default value.